# Can I sync drafts to gMail from iPhone mail?

Tags: data-synchronization, ios, gmail

I have gmail set up via exchange. My drafts aren't syncing back to the server. Should they be? Is there a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is limitation of GMail via Exchange on iOS.

The only way to have draft support is to use the GMail template when adding a new mail account.

Comment: in which case, you don't get push. :(

Comment: that's absolutely right